# Dart: Use Futures to asynchronously fill a static var

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have defined a static var as Map for all instances of my element. If it contains a specific key, it should use the value. If the key is not contains the instance should get the data with a request and save it in the static map, so other instances could use it.

```dart
static var data = new Map();

func() {
  if (Elem.data.containsKey(['key']) {
    list = Elem.data['key'];
  }
  else {
    Helper.getData().then((requestedData) {
      list = requestedData;
      Elem.data.addAll({ 'key' : requestedData });
  }
}
```

The Problem is that all my instances go into the else, since the key is not contained in the Map at the moment the other instances are at the if. So i need them to wait, until the Data is in the Map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
static var data = new Map();
static Completer _dataCompleter;

Future<bool> func() {
  if(_dataCompleter == null) {
    _dataCompleter = new Completer();
    Helper.getData().then((requestedData) {
      list = requestedData;
      Elem.data.addAll({ 'key' : requestedData });
      _dataCompleter.complete(true);
    })
  } 
  if(_dataCompleter.isCompleted) {
    return new Future.value(true);
  } 
  return _dataCompleter.future;
}
```

and call it like

```dart
func().then((success) => /* continue here when `key` in `data` has a value.
```

Comment: Both method work to fill the Map. I'm aware of that, and that why i ask how i can make the other instances wait until the map is filled

Comment: Every instance still does a request... Shouldnt the Completer be static, so every instance can see it?

Comment: You are right. I had that at first but made a different attempt and then forgot it.

Comment: Great this works. Thanks. Sadly I'm having a hard time understanding Futures and Completers..

Comment: I modified the code a bit. I haven't tried it but I think this is necessary for calls that come in when `getData` is already finished. I had a hard time too at first but you get used to it. Just don't try to avoid it, you will see you can't avoid it in Dart. The upcoming async/await will make it a lot easier (already availabel in experimental state by passing a flag when launching Dart VM or Dartium)

Answer (score 2):

In response to Günter Zöchbauer. I generally avoid using `Completer`s directly:

```dart
static var data = new Map();
static Future _pendingFuture;

Future func() {
  if (_pendingFuture == null) {
    _pendingFuture = Helper.getData().then((requestedData) {
      list = requestedData;
      Elem.data.addAll({ 'key' : requestedData });
    });
  }
  return _pendingFuture;
}
```